# Remove hover style?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have a table and a style like this:

```
.highlightrows tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #aaaaff;
 }
```

Then I have a click handler on this row to remove the row from the table and add it to another table. When I click on the mouse I'm of course hover over the row and therefor is the style applied.
My problem is that when I append it to the other table the hover-style is not removed. How can I remove the style in jQuery?

Edit:
I've made a jsFiddle to discribe my problem. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhYgg/17/)

Comment: can you show your code may that's helpful

Comment: @ErikZ, I still didn't get your problem.... :(

Comment: It seems to be a problem with IE8. My company still uses it. :(

Answer (score 1):

you have two tables... why not do it this way??

```
#table1.highlightrows tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #aaaaff;
}

#table2.highlightrows tbody tr:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

Comment: The best solution so far. But instead of adding a separate `id` for the table, just change the `class` of the new table. A table with .hightlightrows class applied which doesn't hightlight the rows doesn't sound right.

Comment: @apnerve yeah! good point... and also, why would the OP has `highlightrows` on the second table... :D

Comment: Hmmm....I want the hovering effect on both tables, but ofcourse only when I'm hovering over a row.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, that seems to be a bug with the browser, as you are no longer hovered over the element.

Anyway, you could try

```
$(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
```

Or otherwise set it to its default color, *after* you move it.

:hover is not a style, and AFAIK you can't remove it from an element - only the browser can do that.  The only thing you can do is force the default style on the actual element

Comment: It is not a bug with the browser but with the code. The another table shouldn't have the class `hightlightrows`.

Comment: Yes it sholud. I want to higlight rows in both tables, BUT only when I'm hover over them. The problem is thet when im hovering over a row and move it, the hovering effect is not removed.

Answer (score 0):

I was just running into this issue.

I had a :hover style in my CSS and while running java script I didn't want :hover to be in effect. I couldn't find a way to remove the class so I decided to overwrite the class by appending a new class with my new attributes to the head.

CSS

```
.myStyle:hover {
    display: block; background: #efefef;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$("head").append("
    <style type='text/css'>
        .myStyle:hover { display: none; background: #ff0000; }
    </style>);
```

hope that helps